# paypal integration according to dynamic choices

Tags: php, paypal

I want to integrate paypal with my website.
I have studied the documentation available on paypal website.

My requirement is

> A user selects a category, based on category course is populated,user selects course and  discount. I want the user to pay through paypal according to the course selected. Also the data should be inserted into a table after successfull payment.

I have checked sample code also but i am unable to figure out how to accomplish this task ie how to make it dynamic according to the user choice. I think ipn would be used but not sure.

Plese help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option for that. Only configured prices.
The only field that doesn't have an price setup is "Donations"

Also in PayPal you can configure the stock that you have for every products, shipping price and tax.